# How do I reinitialise jquery validation after loading form through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am loading a form via an ajax call. On the form I need to use jquery validation to validate the one text area.

The validation call is at the bottom of the page, but because the form isn't present when the page loads, I need to re-initalise it when the form has been loaded.

This is the code for the jquery validation:

```
class OpAuthSignIn {

static initValidationNotes() {
    jQuery('.js-validation-notes').validate({
        errorClass: 'invalid-feedback animated fadeInDown',
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorPlacement: (error, e) => {
            jQuery(e).parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
        },
        highlight: e => {
            jQuery(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        success: e => {
            jQuery(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('is-invalid');
            jQuery(e).remove();
        },
        rules: {
            'notefield': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'notefield' : 'Enter some details for the note'
        }
    });
}

static init() {
    this.initValidationNotes();
}
}

// Initialize when page loads
jQuery(() => { OpAuthSignIn.init(); });
```

Then this is my ajax call script. I have commented where I need to initilise the validation:

```
function openNotes(testID){
        
        var dataString = 'pupilID=<?=$pupilID?>&testID='+testID+'&forename=<?=$forename?>'; 
        
        console.log("datastring: "+dataString);
        
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "note_sidebar.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                console.log("html returned: "+html);
                
                if (html!="Error"){
                    
                    document.getElementById("sidebarTitle").innerHTML = "Notes";
                    document.getElementById("sidebarContent").innerHTML = html;
                    
                    //I need to now initialise the form
                    
                }else{
            
                    swal("Opps!", "There was an error loading the notes", "warning");
                }
                
            }
            });
        
    }
```

Comment: Initialize it the same way you do on page load

Comment: Ths is me being stupid...putting the line jQuery(() => { OpAuthSignIn.init(); }); in my function was all I needed! Thanks for the prompt.